# How to farm possibly unstable code out to a separate process?

Tags: python, web.py

I've got a web.py server that has a problem: it's supposed to take input from the user and process it.  Some of this processing takes place in a `.pyd` that I didn't write and I can't debug or rebuild, and it has some bugs.  There are certain inputs that can cause it to throw an Access Violation, which for some reason cannot be caught and causes `python.exe` to crash, bringing down the server.

This is unacceptable, but also unavoidable, so I need to change the rules a little.

What I'd like to do is to move the unstable functionality, the interface to which is already cleanly contained in a single .py file, out of the server and have the server launch it as a separate process.  If it works successfully, it should print the output, which (conveniently enough) is a text string.  If not, the server should detect that the separate process crashed, and return `HTTP 500`.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to do multi-process work in Python.

How would I implement this?